# How to pretty print Jettison JSONObject in Jersey?

Tags: json, jersey, pretty-print, jettison

How can I pretty print JSON output in Jersey using Jettison?

I'm passing a JSONObject (from Jettison) as a response entity to Jersey. I would like to configure whether the output is formatted / pretty printed or not.

I'm fine with a flag that forces all output to be pretty printed.

Thanks,

Rutger

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

First, I add a query param, such as 'presentable':

```
public Response getResource(@QueryParam("presentable") boolean presentable) {
...
```

then later, when we've fetched the data can do this:

```
    return Response.ok()
        .entity(presentable ? myJson.toString(4) : myJson.toString())
        .build();
```

Sorry no one's gotten you a response sooner.  Hope it's still valuable to you.